# Navigate to similarly named Java/Scala packages

Tags: java, scala, intellij-idea

I am coding in IntelliJ in a multi-module repo. I often find myself in a situation where I am editing the source of code of `com.acme.something.MyClass` (under module `a`) and I want to "jump" to  the same package but under a different module. This other module can sometimes be `a-tests` but sometimes it is a non-testing module (e.g., module `b`) which defines the same Java package (e.g., because the business logic is split across two modules, each implementing a specific aspect).

`<ADD>`

The point is that I do not necessarily know/remember the name of the classes in that other folder (when I do remember, I hit `Double Shift` 
to search everywhere for that class name).

`</ADD>`

So, I am wondering whether there UI support for quickly navigating to identically named packages in other modules in the repo?

Comment: I think you can hit double <kbd>Shift</kbd> and then search for `MyClass` or `MC`, if you have your modules within the same project.

Comment: thanks @Abby. Please see the addition.